# Filtro de categorias no Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Preciso criar um filtro destes jogos onde ao clicar no botão abaixo ele recomende um dos produtos do Woocommerce, respectivamente categorizado em "entrada", "recomendado" e "alta-performance".

Cada jogo é um CPT, e eles tem as categorias respectivamente.
Cada PC tem no seu cadastro de qual categoria ele pertence também.

Preciso alinhar um jogo "entrada" com o PC "entrada" e um PC "alta-performance" com os jogos "alta-performance" por exemplo.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: A categoria é compartilhada? Ou são taxonomias diferentes? O que aparece quando vc visita uma página da categoria ( /category/entrada/ ) ?

Comment: São diferentes, a do CPT jogo é uma e a do Woocommerce é outra.